# Pattern to match any character until boundary character

Tags: java, regex

I have the string:
String myStr = "Operation=myMethod\nDataIn=A;B;C;D\nDataOut=X;Y;Z\n"

and I want to match DataIn.

I have the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Operation=myMethod.*DataIn=(.*)?\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStr);
if (matcher.find()) {
  return matcher.group(1);
}
```

The problem is that it is returning: "A;B;C;D\nDataOut=X;Y;Z\n"

I tried with the patter: "Operation=myMethod.*DataIn=(.*?\n)"
It then returns "A;B;C;D\n". I don't want the final "\n" to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `(.*)` in your regex by `([^\n]*)` to match until the line-break, or `([^\b]*)` to match until any boundary character.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Operation=myMethod.*DataIn=([^\\n]*)?\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStr);
if (matcher.find()) {
  return matcher.group(1);
}
```

The `[^...]` construct in a character class that means match any character that isn't in this set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Operation=myMethod.*?DataIn=([^\\n]*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This will match until 0 or more characters in group #1 until `\n` is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=DataIn=)(.+?)(?=\\n)
```

**CODE**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=DataIn=)(.+?)(?=\\n)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStr);
if (matcher.find()) 
{
   return matcher.group(1);
}
```

**INPUT**

```
Operation=myMethod\nDataIn=A;B;C;D\nDataOut=X;Y;Z\n
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A;B;C;D
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Regex

```
(?s)(?<=DataIn=)(.+?)(?=\n)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]